# IBM Cloud Private 2.1 - Cloudant fails to start

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

Created 3 VMs with 16G storage and 4 Gig of memory and Ubuntu 16.4. 
While installing the ICP 2.1 CE, the step of deploying cloudant is failing with timeout (50 times).

Tried a few things:

1. Pulled "ibmcom/icp-datastore" locally - no change
2. Added - kubelet_extra_args: ["--cgroup-driver=systemd"] - no change in behavior

Here is the actual output:

```
TASK [addon : Deploying cloudant] **************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [addon : Waiting for cloudant to start] ***************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (50 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (49 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (48 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (47 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (46 retries left).
```

Answer (score 1):

With 2.1, if you're enabling various management services, you'll need more disk and more memory on the master nodes.

The documentation recommends either 4G of memory on the master, if you're using management nodes; or 8G of memory on the master if you're not using the management node role.

Separately though, I'm not sure if it's a typo of whether you meant 160G of disk or really 16G of disk, which won't be sufficient on the master.

You can provide some additional information to help resolve this issue:

- Run the installer with verbose options.

  `docker run -e LICENSE=accept --net=host \
    -t -v "$(pwd)":/installer/cluster \
    ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0 install -vvv | tee -a install_log.txt`

The log may provide additional context about why it's failing.

- Provide the logs from the IBM Cloud Private datastore container.

  `docker logs $(docker ps | grep icp-datastore | cut -f 1 -d ' ')`

What you should see, in a good case looks like:

```
Volume Mount not available
Accepting License
Running Runit in Background Process
FEDERATION_RESULT
icp-ds-0
FEDERATOR Pod.
...
Node Added to Cluster Successfully
Initialize Cluster
INFO:cast.database:Creating the system databases.
INFO:cast.database:Creating the security documents
Cluster Initialization Successfully
```

Comment: Looks Pod restarted. Installing Database from a cluster config file
Running Runit in Background Process
INFO:cast.system:Updating the repository cache.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libcsmap-cloudant libgeos-cloudant-3.4.2 libsnappy-cloudant
  libleveldb-cloudant libspatialindex-cloudant cloudant-db cloudant-metrics
  cloudant-mustgather cloudant-rebal cloudant-search cloudant-dbnode
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
Selecting previously unselected package libcsmap-cloudant.

Comment: Hi Michael, I do not see the good case like you are showing. How can I send the logs?

Answer (score 0):

The VMs appear to be undersized.  Please try again with more CPU, RAM and Storage allocated to VMs.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html

Comment: The disk size was 16G and changed it to 160G and tried. Same result.